# How to run my destructor before close the Qt Console Application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to run my destructor before click the close button of Qt console application.I found this on stackoverflow,[Destructor not called in Qt console scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465172/destructor-not-called-in-qt-console-scenario) .

I have tried to get the return value ,and return the value after.but it is nothing to help.

```
class MyClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << "MyClass()";
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << "~MyClass()";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass my;

    int ret = a.exec();

    qDebug() << "this line will not run.";

    return ret;
}
```

1. I want to know why it doesn't run my destructor.
2. If I want to run it.how?

I want it to output `MyClass()` and `this line will not run.` and `~MyClass()` when I click the close button.

Comment: Because calling .exec on QCoreApplication enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called.

Comment: The documentation for `QCoreApplication::exec()` is self-explanatory about this  ....   "We recommend that you connect clean-up code to the `aboutToQuit()` signal, instead of putting it in your application's `main()` function because on some platforms the `exec()` call may not return. For example, on Windows when the user logs off, the system terminates the process after Qt closes all top-level windows. Hence, there is no guarantee that the application will have time to exit its event loop and execute code at the end of the `main()` function after the `exec()` call."

Comment: Your class is instanciated on the stack and will be destructed once you get out of your scope. Use a pointer to allocate it on the heap and call the destructor with delete when app is about to quit : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer right now (so anybody, feel free to do so), but solution to your problem should be found behind these two links: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/26658707/1717300 (note: not duplicate, doesn't cover how to do it in Qt).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this. I'm not sure if it works on Windows since I don't have it right now, but it work on Linux.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << "MyClass()";
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << "~MyClass()";
    }
};

void SigInt_Handler(int)
{
    qDebug() << "Interrupt received";
    qApp->quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass my;

    signal(SIGINT, &SigInt_Handler);

    int ret = a.exec();

    return ret;
}
```

Also your `MyClass` should extend `QObject` if you use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in it.

When pressing `Ctrl+C` this will be printed:

```
Interrupt received
~MyClass()
```

Comment: I did a quick test, and in that it seems `aboutToQuit` is not emitted, when I close the console window. Logging to file and flushing after every log line, the lines before `a.exec()` are written, but nothing after it, nor from `aboutToQuit` receiver lambda.

Comment: Yep, I was a bit too quick to answer, I thought it would work but it's not. I'm trying other approaches right now, but I don't think there's an easy way.

Comment: See my comment under the Q.

Comment: @hyde yep, that actually works, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but Qt isn't "async safe" so you are not allowed to call Qt methods from signal handlers... So the links under the Q.

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows

Answer (score 0):

You should use *SetConsoleCtrlHandler* function for that. In the example below both *aboutToQuit* slot and *QMediaDownloader* destructor are called after pressing the console close ('X') button:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include "downloader.h"

BOOL WINAPI QuitHandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    qApp->quit();

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::SetConsoleCtrlHandler(QuitHandlerRoutine, TRUE);

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMediaDownloader downloader;
    QObject::connect(&a, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &downloader, &QMediaDownloader::aboutToQuit);

    return a.exec();
}
```